# sites saved rather than opening index.php

Tags: php

Index.php file is not opening when I have upload the same in webserver to publish in internet. But the same is working fine in localhost xampp web server. To resolve this issue, I believe we need to do some modifications in PHP settings in Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0. Could anyone please help me to do the settings

Comment: Is PHP Installed at all??

Comment: yes and now issue resolved by changing the error_reporting value to "off" in PHP settings

Answer (score 0):

Activate php interpretation in your webserver settings.

Either php is not supported or not yet activated in your webserver.

Or maybe your files have a wired ending? i.e. not php but php3? Then you have to tell your webserver to interpret this filetype with php as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. My issue has been resolved by the modification of PHP settings. I changed the value of error_reporting to "off".